# Joi: require at least 1 field using .or()

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, joi

I'm trying to require the presence of at least 1 field between "years" and "months" (and allow both as well of course).
If "months" has a value, then "years" is optional, and the opposite would be true as well.
That's the current code that I have using .or() method, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    const schema = Joi.object({
    software: Joi.object({
        value: Joi.string(),
        label: Joi.string(),
    })
        .required()
        .messages({ "any.required": "Software can't be empty", "object.base": "Software can't be empty" })
        .label("Software"),

    years: Joi.object()
        .keys({
            value: Joi.number(),
            label: Joi.number(),
        })
        .optional()
        .allow(null),

    months: Joi.object()
        .keys({
            value: Joi.number(),
            label: Joi.number(),
        })
        .optional()
        .allow(null),

    proficiency: Joi.number()
        .required()
        .messages({ "any.required": "Proficiency is required", "number.base": "Proficiency is required" }),
}).or("years", "months");

const {
    register,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, isDirty },
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
} = useForm({
    resolver: joiResolver(schema),
    mode: "onSubmit",
    defaultValues: {
        proficiency: null,
        software: null,
        years: null,
        months: null,
    },
});
```

I've also tried something like that :

```
    const schema = Joi.object({
    software: Joi.object({
        value: Joi.string(),
        label: Joi.string(),
    })
        .required()
        .messages({ "any.required": "Software can't be empty", "object.base": "Software can't be empty" })
        .label("Software"),

    years: Joi.when("months", {
        is: null,
        then: Joi.object({
            value: Joi.number(),
            label: Joi.number(),
        }).required(),
        otherwise: Joi.allow(null),
    }),

    months: Joi.when("years", {
        is: null,
        then: Joi.object({
            value: Joi.number(),
            label: Joi.number(),
        }).required(),
        otherwise: Joi.allow(null),
    }),

    proficiency: Joi.number()
        .required()
        .messages({ "any.required": "Proficiency is required", "number.base": "Proficiency is required" }),
});
```

but in that case, i'm getting the following error: *item added into group months created a dependencies error*

Also trying the following with .alternatives() testing with https://joi.dev/tester/ :

```js
Joi.alternatives().try(
  Joi.object({
    software: Joi.object({
      value: Joi.string(),
      label: Joi.string(),
    }).required().messages({ "any.required": "Software can't be empty", "object.base": "Software can't be empty" }).label("Software"),
    proficiency: Joi.number().required().messages({ "any.required": "Proficiency is required", "number.base": "Proficiency is required" }),
    years: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).optional().allow(null),
    months: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).optional().allow(null),
  }).or("years", "months"),
  Joi.object({
    software: Joi.object({
      value: Joi.string(),
      label: Joi.string(),
    }).required().messages({ "any.required": "Software can't be empty", "object.base": "Software can't be empty" }).label("Software"),
    proficiency: Joi.number().required().messages({ "any.required": "Proficiency is required", "number.base": "Proficiency is required" }),
    years: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).required(),
    months: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).required(),
  })
)
```

These data are passing the test, but the 1st should should not pass:

```js
{ 
 years: null,
 months: null,
 proficiency: 5,
 software: {label: "android", value: "1"},
}
// >> this one should not pass the test

or 

{ 
 years: {label: 2, value: 2},
 months: null,
 proficiency: 5,
 software: {label: "android", value: "1"},
}

or

{ 
 years: null,
 months: {label: 6, value: 6},
 proficiency: 5,
 software: {label: "android", value: "1"},
}

or

{ 
 years: {label: 3, value: 3},
 months: {label: 7, value: 7},
 proficiency: 5,
 software: {label: "android", value: "1"},
}
```

All 4 scenario pass the validation even though the 1st shouldn't.
Also, in my app it's only throwing this error, instead of the custom messages I've wrote (eg. when no software or no proficiency"

```js
{
    "": {
        "message": "\"value\" does not match any of the allowed types",
        "type": "alternatives.match"
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `.optional()` from months and years

Comment: I tried but that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Joi.alternative()` and provide either `years` or `months` key using `xor` or both of them.

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
  Joi.object({
    years: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number(), }).optional().allow(null),
    months: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).optional().allow(null),
  }).xor('years', 'months'),
  Joi.object({
    years: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number(), }).required().allow(null),
    months: Joi.object().keys({ value: Joi.number(), label: Joi.number() }).required().allow(null),
  })
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working as well

`message: "\"value\" does not match any of the allowed types"`

Comment: Please share one sample test data here.

Comment: I've edited my post with the schema using .alternatives() in the last code snippet

Comment: Can you also add your test data as well.

Comment: yes sorry, i've updated my post again

Comment: All the shared data is passing on https://joi.dev/tester/  The reason of your validation to be failing could be that either the value is undefined or empty string in some scenario.

Comment: There's actually something wrong with the schema, as the scenario where both 'months' and 'years' are empty is passing the test, when it should be at least 1 of them, or both of them (3 possible scenario as in the original post)

Comment: The new Joi schema which you have shared should have `xor` not `or`. That will not  allow both year and month to be null. In the answer I have mentioned it to be `xor`

Comment: I've tried with xor as well and it's still not working unfortunately